# laravel where to put classes used as function return types

Tags: php, laravel

In typescript I would have a `/models` folder with classes that represent actual entities and a `/types` folder for interfaces that are mostly used to define the structure of function arguments and return values.

Where would I put classes in a laravel project that are used for this purpose?

Comment: Does it matter? That's why [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) were introduced, put them anywhere you want to.

Comment: Laravel doesn't ship with a Models folder. You can create it and put `User` in it, and the rest of the models. You're gonna have to modify some files that need this class. Now, for this "types" definition, I don't think Laravel needs it

Answer (score 0):

You can freely choose how you structure your application. However it is recommended to put application code under the `/app` folder.

I always put my models in `/app/models` and have them in the corresponding namespace. You could do the same for your types and any other type of classes.